# Passing a variable from ChromeClient back to WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

All WebView file upload tutorials/guides/articles shows me to use **WebChromeClient** like this

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
         public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,              FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                 mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;
                // Launch Intent for picking file
                return true;
         }
});
```

so here we are not using our own **WebChromeClient** class from separate file extending original one, we just declare new one straight as **setWebChromeClient** parameter overriding all needed methods, and it works cool but what if my client is in separate file?

What if my **MainActivity** class looks like this

```
import com.example.app.ModifiedWebViewClient;
```

with using it latter

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new ModifiedWebChromeClient());
```

and my **ModifiedWebChromeClient** is

```
public class ModifiedWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
     ....
```

how i will pass **filePathCallback** from **onShowFileChooser** back to **MainActivity**?

Comment: You can take a static variable in MainActivity, Assign filePathCallback value to that static variable.

MainActivity.staticvalriable=filePathCallback;

Comment: It works! Thank you, you can post it as answer, i'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access that value using static variable.
Declare a static variable in MainActivity, 
Assign filePathCallback value to that static variable.

```
  MainActivity.staticvariable=filePathCallback;
```